# Media web part in SharePoint 2013 (Office 365)

Tags: 2013, web-part, office-365, ribbon

Adding a Media web part in order to add a video to a page only rarely allows the setting of the Behavior (Change Media, Change Image). Selecting Edit Web Part for the Media web part supposedly reveals a Media tab.

In Internet Explorer (version 11), it very rarely does. No matter whether I use Compatibility View or not. Sometimes I can get to the Media tab if editing in Firefox or Chrome, but not always.

[image: no Media tab]

When I am able to see the Media tab (usually when I first add a new Media web part to a page, or if the phase of the moon is right and no cats are howling), I don't seem to be able to access the mysterious Player Styles, even though I have site Owner permissions.

[image: player styles not available]

Has anyone else run across this?